# Memory overflow when using keras.utils.Sequence

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to train a CNN on a rather big dataset (30GB and about 30000 images) containing images of size 512x512. I am trying to use `keras.utils.Sequence` to fit this dataset in memory, but I am facing problem with GPU memory overflow. As I can see from logs, Keras is allocation a huge tensor for EACH layer in CNN layer.

I can easily pass about 3000 images dataset directly to `model.fit()` function. However, when I use `keras.utils.Sequence` I face problem below.

For example, I am using batch_size for `keras.utils.Sequence` of size 1500 and first layer is `model.add(layers.Conv2D(4, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(512, 512, 1)))`, so the output  of that layer should be of shape [510,510,4].

However, Keras allocates a tensor of size [1500,510,510,4] for that layer, and it do that for each layer of CNN allocation it in shape like [1500,x,x,x]. When I change `keras.utils.Sequence` batch_size, the first number decreases (so with 1000 it will be [1000,x,x,x])

As I understand, Keras allocates a huge tensor for each layer and that is why I run out of memory. How to force Keras not to do that? Why it tries to allocate such huge tensors for each layer when using `keras.utils.Sequence`?

Comment: I think you should rethink on what the batch size is and how it works, using a batch size of 1500 is crazy and you should use a much lower value (32-128), which will not have a large memory requirement.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy then why, when I use fit with 3000 dataset it is all ok? With that size epoch is about 5s, but with keras.utils.Sequence and batch_size 30 it is...well it is 10 hours

Comment: That seems to be a completely different question. Please note that details really matter and you are already asking vague questions.

Comment: For all we know, your 3000 images passed in "directly" is via a numpy array, which automatically results in batches of a given size, with defaults to 32 if not specified. But as Dr. Snoopy said, this is just guessing since your question lacks necessary details. Please study the documention of model.fit since there are many special cases and different behaviors: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit